# Kivy Issues with .py and .kv

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.7.9
My code:

In Main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class Main(Widget):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

In main.kv:

```
<Main>
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GidLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name: "

            TextInput:
                multiline:False

            Label:
                texxt: "Email: "
            
            TextInput:
                multiline:False

        Button:
            text:"Submit"
```

Error(1):

In the .py file, 'Main' in 'Main().run()' is underlined with:

```
Instance of 'Main' has no 'run' member
```

Error(2):

In the .kv file '' is underlined with:

```
Kivy files require #:Kivy
```

I can't figure out how to fix, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two bugs, one in the kv code, and the second in the python code.

In the kv code change the `<Main>` to `<MyGrid>`.
MyGrid class is the root widget, not the Main class. The Main class is only responsible to build the widget tree.

In the python code, change the return of the build method in the Main class so that it returns a MyGrid instance. And the Main should inherit from the App class, not from the Widget class.

```
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
```

Comment: When I make these changes, it says: NameError: name 'MyWidget' is not defined

Comment: My fault, it should be: return MyGrid()

Comment: I made the changes, but the .kv code still has the same error. And now kivy says "Unable to get a Window, abort."

Comment: Maybe add a semicolon in the kv code after the MyGrid: <MyGrid>:

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.11.0/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file), a `kv` file:

> Syntax of a kv File A Kivy language file must have .kv as filename
> extension.
>
> The content of the file should always start with the Kivy header,
> where version must be replaced with the Kivy language version you’re
> using. For now, use 1.0:

```
#:kivy `1.0`

# content here
```

Then, in your `py` file. an application must extend `App` not `Widget`. Also, the `build()` method must return a `Widget`, not an instance of the `App`. And, if your `App` is named `Main`, then you should choose a different name for the root widget of your `App`.

The rules in the `kv` file describe how to build widgets, and cannot be applied to building an `App`. They can describe the building of the root widget of the `App`, but not the `App` itself.